# How to get sum of rows for last columns? in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am exporting an Excel file using `Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel.` I have Projects > Modules (for each Project) > Activities (for each module) > dates > time (for each date). I can display time for each date, and then I am summing up the total hours spent on each activity, but then I have to sum up total hours for all activities under each module. Which I am not able to do so?

**Excel data**

```
# Project A #
## Module A      date1 date2 date3  total  total2
### Activity A  1      2     3       6      18 (this is what I wanna display)
### Activity B  1      2     3       6
### Activity C  1      2     3       6
```

**Blade**

```php
@foreach($project as $pro)
    @foreach($pro->modules as $mod)
        @foreach($activity as $act)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$pro->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$mod->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$act->name}}</td>
                @foreach($time[$pro->id][$mod->id][$act->id] as $log)
                    <td>{{$log}}</td>
                @endforeach
                <td>
                    {{ array_sum($time[$pro->id][$mod->id][$act->id])}}
                    {{-- This is where I get the total --}}
                </td>
                <td>{{-- Here I want to display total2 --}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to do the work before rendering in blade. This sort of work is best done BEFORE you send to the template context. Then you can build an array that makes sense to easily loop through. You have your loop values in one array, then just a separate value for the total2, and you use the $loop->first check to include it on the first line there.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff9b7086a843ca3e5b3ac0d1eaa241d5cfb592bd

Comment: @Beginner thank you for the effort but now i get this 


total  total2
7  7
9 16
3 19
4 23
5 28

even If i get the last value which is the total of 5 activities would be good enough but currently is adding up all the numbers

Comment: @Trent thank you for the suggestion would try it :)

Comment: @HashaamAhmed http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/633abbe02f60c4c7ee630136c370f4d57b796f9f sorry I misplace the `$total = 0;`

Comment: @Trent now it doesnt add up :(

7 7
9 9
....

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with a very powerfull tool - collections. You should deffinitely take a look at the [awailable methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections#available-methods). Also, awoid using any kind of calculations in your view files and process the data you wish to output before passing it to the view

Comment: thanks for your comment, would be careful next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Sum it on the controller, add a property on the objects called "sum" and then display it on the blade

```
$activity->setAttribute('sum', 'sumresult');
```